# Turning off Perspective Divide

Tags: opengl

Is there a way, in OpenGL, to switch off the automatic perspective divide?
I'd like to see the effect a perspective projection has by itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can "turn off" the perspective divide easily enough by putting 1.0 in the `W` component of `gl_Position`. However, I don't think you fully understand what this will do.

Perspective projection is based on doing such a division. Simply removing that math from the equation, while still using a perspective projection matrix, will not yield reasonable results.

So merely "turning off" the division will not allow you to "see the effect a perspective projection has by itself". It will create a generally nonsensical mess of triangles.

What you probably want to do is switch to using an orthographic projection instead of a perspective projection. That is a matter of what projection matrix you use.

Comment: Does the perspective projection matrix simply clip/cut anything outside the viewing frustrum?

Comment: @Edward: It's a matrix multiply; it doesn't "clip/cut" anything. You need to take some time and investigate how OpenGL transformations and so forth work. I can't really explain it to you piecemeal, and there are plenty of sites online that can help.