# How can I set gl_Position's w component to 1?

Tags: opengl

In my vertex shader, I'd like to set the w component to 1.

How can this be done, after

```
gl_Position =  MVP * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace, 1);
```

Comment: why do you think you need to?

Comment: I wanted to switch off perspective divide.

Comment: @Edward - "how do I switch off perspective divide?" might have been a better question then; ask about what you want to do, not how you want to do it.  Further reading: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Then don't use a perspective projection but an orthographic projection matrix instead

Comment: I just wanted to see the effect switching it off had on a perspective projection. Seems to yield very similar results to an orthographic projection, when rendering a simple coloured cube.

Comment: @MaximusMinimus In fact, he already asked about it. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/152060/turning-off-perspective-divide

Answer (score 4):

You can use swizzles to access specific coordinates in the vector.

`gl_Position.w = 1.0;`